# Bash script that accepts options given after arguments in command line

Tags: bash, arguments, options

I have a bash script that accepts a number of optional flags and two required arguments. Currently, if the command line call is `~/script.sh -a -b arg1 arg2` it works just fine, but if the call is `~/script.sh arg1 arg2 -a -b` it fails to recognize that `-a` and `-b` were set. Here is a trivial example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while :; do
    case $1 in
        -a)
            flag_a=true
        ;;
        -b) 
            flag_b=true
        ;;
        *) ## cause of problem: breaks the loop when the first argument is encountered
            break
    esac
    shift
done
arg_1=$1
arg_2=$2
if [ -z ${arg_1:+x} ] || [ -z ${arg_2:+x} ]; then
    echo -e "\n:-( ERROR: two arguments are required" | tee -a /dev/tty 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
flag_a=${flag_a:-false}
flag_b=${flag_b:-false}
if [ "$flag_a" = true ]; then
    echo "arg_1 is $arg_1"
fi
if [ "$flag_b" = true ]; then
    echo "arg_2 is $arg_2"
fi
if [ ! "$flag_a" = true ] && [ ! "$flag_b" = true ]; then
    echo "no options set"
fi
exit 0
```

Is there a way to accept optional flags that are listed after the required arguments? Can I somehow save the arguments found by `*)` and then add them back to the `$*` array after finishing the `while` loop?

Comment: You know what the problem is; why can’t you fix it yourself? You know that the `break` is the problem; so take it out. Now think about what *should* be in the `*)` case code.

Comment: By convention, options should come before other operands on the command line, so what your current code is doing is correct (apart from not using `getopts`). Calling the script with options _after_ non-option arguments is an error in using the script.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48720056

Comment: @Kusalananda, thank you for that insight on convention. For some reason, I had thought `getopts` didn't work with long options, but it does! I'll look into that. Thanks.

Comment: @Josh Hmm... I've never used `getopts` with long options, so I can't say that it would work. However, there does not seem to be any long options in this question.

Comment: i use that solution in my scripts and it is working fine, i can mix up arguments and options as i like, it is always detected right. i remove all valid options and keep the rest in positional parameters, that has the benefit i can pass whole "$@" (after cleaning) to whatever command and all arguments keep it's whitespaces